# Create Mousedownevent on contenteditable HTML

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Trying to implement a custom widget extending HTML.
It has contenteditable set to true and shall support setting the caret below the mouse on hovering over.
For this purpose, I want to fire a programmatic Mousedown event.

```
void calledWithNativeEventFromHovering(NativeEvent nativeEvent){

    NativeEvent mouseDownEvent = Document.get().createMouseDownEvent( 1, nativeEvent.getScreenX(), nativeEvent.getScreenY(), nativeEvent.getClientX(), nativeEvent.getClientY(), false, false, false, false, NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT );

    //Variant 1
    DomEvent.fireNativeEvent( mouseDownEvent, this, getElement() );

    //Variant 2
    getElement().dispatchEvent( mouseDownEvent );
}
```

It does not trigger setting the caret, however I can catch both events with a mousedown handler.
For debugging purposes, I looked at the respective native events.

*Actual mousedown click: preventDefault: false, currentTarget: element of the widget*

*Variant 1: preventDefault: false, currentTarget: null*

*Variant 2: preventDefault: true, currentTarget: element of the widget*

How to create a Native MouseDownEvent which acts exactly like the one from an actual clickdown? Open for JSNI suggestions, too.

Comment: I would recommend using the gwt FocusPanel for handling this. It is a great way to help manage the events for things like this without having to use the NativeEvents. This will also allow you to dispatch the events using fireEvent rather than the element dispatch.

Comment: If not then you need to make sure you have the DOM.sinkEvents() on your element to register for the event.